# Linux off a Flash Drive

Tags: linux, usb, dual-boot, live-usb, portability

I want to run Linux off of a flash drive. I'm already dual booting Windows 10, and Ubuntu on my laptop, and have burnt the mint ISO onto a flash drive. Every time I load it live, it takes me to a guest user, and the changes made, the programs installed get reset. Is there a way to save the changes, possibly creating a user and stuff?

PS: Please don't ask me to install it onto a flash drive, I wanted to use the flash drive on any PC/Laptop.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/ (I used a well-known search engine to search for *linux live save data* and this was the first result. I didn't check if this is the "best" result.)

Comment: If you want to be able to use the flash drive as a normal flash drive as well, you can manually partition it and create a big FAT32 partition on it.

Comment: @Bodo thanks, it was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

I use YUMI multiboot to create the USB boot drive. In YUMI when you make the bootable USB you can set a persistent file size for storing changes while running off of the USB drive.  This will take some of the space on the USB for storing the changes you make while running. 
[image]

BTW your post is confusing. 
The first sentence states you want to run Linux off a flash drive. 
The last sentence says don't ask me to install onto a flash drive. 
Cannot have both???

Comment: umm... i meant that i didn't want to install it onto a flash drive, using another one, like how i'd do on my computer's hard drive... i want to use it on any pc i plug the drive into